# Check if PrimaryKey exists with ponyorm

Tags: python, ponyorm

I am trying to use pony orm to see if a primary key exists.  I got this far, but it always throws a error.

```
class Favorite(db.Entity):
    game = Required(Game)
    user = Required(User)
    date_favorited = Required(datetime)
    PrimaryKey(user, game)
```

Here is the function

```
    if Favorite.get(lambda: user, game) is not None:
        favorited = 1
```

Here is the errro

```
TypeError: The second positional arguments should be globals dictionary. Got: Game[12]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was helped out in the [github repo](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues/134#issuecomment-119537822)

```
if Favorite.exists(user=x, game=y):
    favorited = 1
```